# Does the location of a stored procedure affect its performance?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I have a large application which contains "modules" such as `Finance`, `HR`, `Sales`, `Customer Service`.

To make the application manageable and to distribute the load, I have decided to give each module its own database on a single server. There is also going to be a `Master` database for holding master information such as information about users, some global lookup tables, and some security stuff.

I am now trying to decide whether to place module-specific stored procedure in their corresponding database, or whether to keep them all in the `Master` database. For example there is a stored procedure named `dbo.sales_customer_orders` that selects data from only the `Sales` database tables. And of course this SP is going to be executed a lot of times by users. Therefore should it be in the `Sales` database or will it be okay to keep it in the `Master` database in terms of performance/scalability/reliability/security.

Does it matter that a stored procedure resides in a different database to the one its selecting from?

Comment: Before you put them into separate databases did you consider a Separate Schema for each module ?????

Comment: Yes I considered a seperate schema but it would mean having all modules in 1 database. Its a multi-tenant application so I can't risk having a single database for everything and everyone. It would crash as more users are added to the system so I decided to 'vertically partition' it by application area i.e. module. Here's more info (look at approach 5)  http://blog.techcello.com/2012/07/database-sharding-scaling-data-in-a-multi-tenant-environment/

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you would not experience an immediate performance penalty by sharding the data across multiple databases and this is actually a common practice in large n-tier applications.  You would obviously experience some minor penalty upon moving the databases to different servers.

You could see this [blog post](http://www.brentozar.com/articles/sharding/)  as well as several others on the site which talk about the correct way to shard data as well as the importance of using multiple connection string's for reads and writes to facilitate scaling and possibly caching layer later on.

Comment: Would it be better then to have the SPs for each module within that module's database. Because if the database was to move servers the SPs within each database wouldn't need to be updated to include the new server name. They can still reference their own database name. E.g. it will always be `select * from [sales].[dbo].[orders]` even if the server changes

Answer (score 1):

How do you actually plan to develop all these databases? If you want to use SSDT, you will be drowned in all those cross-database dependencies. Besides, your procedure in question being resided in the `head` database makes no sense if, for example, some particular customer decided not to buy the Sales module (and there is no Sales database anywhere around). In this case, calling it will lead to some very unpleasant and unexpected consequences, such as batch being aborted and (possibly) transaction left open.

Keep similar things together; otherwise, there will be no modularity in your approach.

Performance-wise, usually there is no difference for cross-database calls within the same SQL Server instance. If your shards are located on different instances, however, the result might be anywhere between "slightly noticeable" to "detrimental" - it depends on many factors, and not all of them can be mitigated by a DBA.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Roger. The SP would be in the `head` database but access to it would be denied to those who don't have the `Sales` module. I think giving people permission to run an SP would be better handled at the application level than database level. The `head` database just stores what permissions organisations and people have.